# Как сделать, чтобы нумерация колонки начиналась после самого большого значения в таблице

Tags: postgresql

Столкнулся с такой проблемой, что при вставке значения link уже существовал, потому что значение link было заполнено вручную. Колонка настроена таким образом

```
ALTER TABLE some_table ALTER COLUMN link ADD GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY (
START WITH 1
INCREMENT BY 1
NO MAXVALUE
NO MINVALUE
CACHE 1
);
```

Как мне сделать так, чтобы заполнялся либо отсутствующий промежуток, либо после максимального значения.
Например есть отсутствующие значения линк между 234 и 254 и при вставке строка в link попадало значение 235.
Или так, в колонке link максимальное значение на данный момент 375 значит следующая вставленная строка получит значение 376.
Пробовал что то на подобии этого

```
ALTER TABLE some_table ALTER COLUMN link ADD GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY (
START WITH COALESCE((SELECT MAX(link) + 1 FROM some_table),1)
INCREMENT BY 1
NO MAXVALUE
NO MINVALUE
CACHE 1
);
```

Но само собой так не работает. В документации найти не получается и на просторах интернета тоже. Очень интересно как это можно реализовать

Comment: `START WITH 376`?

Comment: Обычно поле-автоинкремент является заодно и первичным ключом... а у вас не так?

Comment: Конкретно в этом случае не так

Comment: Видимо без триггера на удаление и вставку, который будет брать максимальный link и счётчик начинать со следующего числа не обойтись